# Apache htaccess: Deny if REQUEST_URI not match cookie value

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, cookies, match

So, after searching for a solution all over this community, my question is as follow:

Im working within the Wordpress enviroment, Apache server. I have a folder within uploads named `/restricted/`. Everything in here (any file extension) **can only be accessed if**:

- A cookie named 'custom_cookie' is set
- **And** this cookie value must be a partial match of the URL request

If these conditions fail, an image is served. Inside this `/restricted/` folder I got a `.htaccess` file. Everything must (prefered) be done in that htaccess file, *not on root* htaccess file.

> The cookie is set by functions.php, no problem with that
>   part. And comments about security is not the question here

This is an url example (localhost): `http://localhost/komfortkonsult/wp-content/uploads/restricted/some-file.jpg?r=870603c9d23f2b7ea7882e89923582d7`

The **first** condition *A cookie named custom_cookie is set*, everything **is working** with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /komfortkonsult/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*uploads/restricted/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !custom_cookie
RewriteRule . /komfortkonsult/restricted.png [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

However, the **next part** Im ***totally out in the blue***, But I tried **and failed** with the following approaches:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} custom_cookie=(.*)$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule . /komfortkonsult/restricted.png [R,L]
```

Likewise:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/ - [E=COOKIE_MATCH:%1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !custom_cookie="%{ENV:COOKIE_MATCH}"
RewriteRule . /komfortkonsult/restricted.png [R,L]
```

Likewise:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} custom_cookie=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !%1 [NC]
RewriteRule . /komfortkonsult/restricted.png [R,L]
```

And so on. I really want to keep this inside the `.htaccess`, instead using validation through a `.php` file call. But **if that is the only solution** to my architechture, *please provide a full working example* (not foo=bar, your redirects goes here...)

> Any other approaches of my objectives are welcome.

Thanks so much for helping me out with this.

/ Intervik

---

**Update** (after accepted answer and working) **example of usage**

The objectives are **one layer** of protection in a Wordpress single install. All media, images or other files, uploaded and attached to pages, **are hidden** *(replaced by an image)* if **A)** the **user is not logged-in** or **B)** The user *is logged in* but *not with the capability of 'edit_post'*.

But the restriction **is only for files uploaded into a unique folder** called `/restricted/`. The folder is resident in the Wordpress original `/uploads/` root. This restricted material is not allowed to be direct-linked or accessable by search engines etc etc. No browser-cache is allowed and restriction must work immediately after log-out. And more... but I think you get it.

The namespace `'custom_cookie'` is just a providing example. And the examples showing the Wordpress install is within a subfolder on localhost. LIKE `h**p://example.com/workspace/`. Remove `'workspace/'` if in root.

**The cookie architecture, functions.php**

```
function intervik_theme_set_custom_cookie(){

    if(is_user_logged_in()){

        global $current_user;

        if(current_user_can('edit_posts')){

            if(!isset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie'])){
                $cookie_value = $current_user->ID . '|' . $current_user->user_login . '|' . $current_user->roles;
                $salt = wp_salt('auth');
                $cookie_hash = hash_hmac('md5', $cookie_value, $salt);
                setcookie('custom_cookie', $cookie_hash, time()+36, '/');
                $_COOKIE['custom_cookie'] = $cookie_hash;
            } else {
                $cookie_value = $current_user->ID . '|' . $current_user->user_login . '|' . $current_user->roles;
                $salt = wp_salt('auth');
                $cookie_hash = hash_hmac('md5', $cookie_value, $salt);
                if($cookie_hash != $_COOKIE['custom_cookie']){
                    setcookie('custom_cookie', '', 1, '/');
                    unset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie']);
                }
            }

        } else {

            if(isset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie'])){
                setcookie('custom_cookie', '', 1, '/');
                unset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie']);
            }
        }

    } else {

        if(isset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie'])){
            setcookie('custom_cookie', '', 1, '/');
            unset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie']);
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'intervik_theme_set_custom_cookie');
```

As you can see, Each cookie **is unique** for **each valid user**, for each +36 seconds period (enough for a page-load - but use +120 for 2 minutes). This "token" is applied to every request send to the the server:

**The link to attachment url filter:**

```
function intervik_restricted_wp_get_attachment_url($url, $post_id){
    if(strpos($url, '/restricted/') !== FALSE){
        if(isset($_COOKIE['custom_cookie'])){
            $url = add_query_arg('r', $_COOKIE['custom_cookie'], $url);
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'intervik_restricted_wp_get_attachment_url', 10, 2);
```

We are not allowing any other query strings. Remark, more filter must be added for sizes, like `wp_get_attachment_image_src` etc etc. But direct links to media, this is enough.

> Replace the `if(current_user_can('edit_posts')` with another
>   `if(is_user_logged_in() ...` changes everything to just login/out
>   users. Then skip the filters in the admin backend with i`f(!is_admin()
>   && strpos($url, '/restricted/')!== FALSE) ...`

**And finally the `.htaccess` file, in the root of the `uploads/restricted/` folder:**

```
# BEGIN Intervik
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
Deny from all
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}::%{QUERY_STRING} !\bcustom_cookie=([0-9a-f]{32})\b.*::r=\1(&|$)
RewriteRule . /workspace/restricted.png? [R,L]

# END Intervik
```

I also placed the nice PNG IMAGE "Restriced Access timeout" in the Wordpress install root. This is also served as thumbnail in Library admin area for non valid administrators. The upload filter or backend is another area.

> We are not protecting Englands financial plans here, but we wanna keep
>   away some paperwork for an organistion and some picures from Google and from
>   your wife.

**Please comment**

Its actually working and you are welcome to comment the flaws or security risks. However, there is also another layer validation with PHP above this layer in our install, but we need speed for not so important stuff.

Comment: This seems to be a very interesting approach -routing the values in this way. If I understand this right, the example is when Wordpress is installed inside a subfolder (localhost enviroment I suppose)?

Comment: Yes, I added information about example are on Wordpres subfolder install on the last edit, Thanks Anna.

Comment: How are you validating the cookie and URL parameter values, apart from simply making sure they are the same?

Comment: The `add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url'` filter populates the users _cookie value_ as `r=query string`. And as people have to understand that this solution requires images **loaded by id** (like galleries or menues) not _hardcoded embedded src:s_ in post and pages. But it is possible to filter the content and wp_get_attachment_imagesrc for more complex output.

Comment: I comfirm it works. But Its easier to adjust if the edit_posts layer is removed, and use this only for logged in vs logged out. After removing `'|' . time()` and changed +36 to 2 minutes, everything feels more stable. The nice _"restricted file" PNG_ is in cache and re-logged in might refresh here...

Comment: Yes `'|' . time()` is a little overkill. Removing this from the example, as the comparsion of exisisting validated cookie fails within 36 seconds.

Comment: "this solution requires images **loaded by id**" - Not sure what you mean? (I don't deal much with WordPress.) Are you saying the browser doesn't actually make the request for `http://localhost/komfortkonsult/wp-content/uploads/restricted/some-file.jpg?r=870603c9d23f2b7ea7882e89923582d7` (so it's "hidden" from the end user)? (Although if not, why make an HTTP request at all and not a direct filesystem request?) What is stopping any user requesting that URL directly (if the filename is known) and injecting the `Cookie` header to bypass the `.htaccess` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some of the correct bits in your different attempts, but you need to bring them together in the correct order.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# custom_cookie value is 32 char hex and must match the value of the "r" URL parameter
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}::%{QUERY_STRING} !\bcustom_cookie=([0-9a-f]{32})\b.*::r=\1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ /komfortkonsult/restricted.png [QSD,R,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to remove the query string from the redirected URL. Alternatively, if you are still using Apache 2.2 then you can append a `?` to the *susbstitution* instead.

Note that the `RewriteBase` is not required here. The `<IfModule>` should also be removed. The `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper is only required if this is intended to work without mod_rewrite being available. It is not. If mod_rewrite is not available then your conditions will simply fail silently and access will be unrestricted. In this case, it is preferable to fail with an error and access is forbidden (for everyone).

**Assumptions:**

- The cookie value is a 32 character hex value (as in your example).
- The `r` URL parameter is always the *first* URL parameter (as in your example).

You mentioned "any file extension", however, redirecting to an image only really "works" if an image is being requested in the first place. If you have files other than images it may be preferable to simply return a 403 Forbidden. (Strictly speaking, sending a 403 is the correct response rather than a 302, followed by 200 OK.) To send a 403 instead, just change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

**How this works...**

- An important point, that is missed from all but one of your examples, is the `r` URL parameter is part of the *query string*, not the URL-path. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. To match the query string you need to compare against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.
- `%{HTTP_COOKIE}::%{QUERY_STRING}` - The `cookie` HTTP request header is joined with the *query string* using a separater (`::`) that is guaranteed to not appear in either value. This forms the *TestString*.
- `!\bcustom_cookie=([0-9a-f]{32})\b.*::r=\1(&|$)` - This is the *CondPattern* that matches the *TestString*. `\b` is a word boundary, so we match only this specific cookie. The value of this cookie is *captured* using `([0-9a-f]{32})`. We then skip over any remaining characters in the cookie header until we get to our separater (`::`). After this we are matching against the *query string* (value of the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in the *TestString*). The "magic" is the `\1` backreference to the first captured group, ie. the cookie value.
- The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the entire pattern. So, the condition is successful when this pattern does not match, ie. when the values of the cookie and URL parameter are different (or not present at all).

**Why your attempts were not working...**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} custom_cookie=(.*)$
> RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)::/\1/?
> ```

- This assumes your cookie is the last cookie in the `Cookie` header. This is difficult to guarantee.
- You are trying to match the cookie value with the entire URL-path (`REQUEST_URI`), so this will never match. It assumes your URL is of the form: `http://localhost/870603c9d23f2b7ea7882e89923582d7`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^/ - [E=COOKIE_MATCH:%1]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !custom_cookie="%{ENV:COOKIE_MATCH}"
> ```

Good, you are checking the *query string* for the URL parameter value. However...

- The first `RewriteRule` never matches because the URL-path never starts with a slash in per-directory (`.htaccess`) context. Consequently, the `COOKIE_MATCH` environment variable is never set.
- The *CondPattern* is a regex, not a plain string, so `%{ENV:COOKIE_MATCH}` is not evaluated - it is seen as a literal string. You've also enclosed this in double quotes, which aren't part of the cookie value either.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} custom_cookie=([^;]+) [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !%1 [NC]
> ```

- Again, you are comparing against the URL-path, not the query string. However, as mentioned above, the `%1` backreference is not evaluated in the *CondPattern*, so this is seen as a literal string anyway.

It is why the `%{VARIABLE}` (and `%1` etc) expressions are not evaluated in the *CondPattern* that we need to use the seemingly complex expression that uses a regex backreference of the form:

```
%{VAR1}@@%{VAR2} ^(.+)@@\1$
```

Comment: Thanks for a professional answer. **I Confirm that the answer is working**. I knew that my idea _should be possible_ but I could not find this task _anywhere through search engines..._ To clearify "any file extension" I ment that the rule must apply to whatever is in that folder, not images only. But the redirect is serving a nice png image  "Restricted file - Access timeout" from the Wordpress install root (looks pretty without the folder url). Thanks again for taking time with your answer and your contribution to the Stack Community.

Comment: At last, we couldnt either find any hint on this, until we saw this question. Searched for days. This is Working for us too.

Comment: Could anyone comment about how to change `{32})\b.*::` if value (length) **is unknown?** or might differ from each user? (not using hash)

Comment: @AnnaEricson The `{32}` isn't strictly required, you could replace it with `+` for instance and it would still "work". However, this would seem to fit the OPs requirements better and is possibly more efficient in this instance. Generally, regex should be as specific as possible. The OP appears to be setting a 32 char hex value, so we might as well validate it as such and fail early if this condition is not met. Remember, the cookie is _user_ supplied data, so could potentially contain anything. (The `{32}` quantifier matches exactly 32 chars of the preceding pattern, no more, no less.)

Comment: @AnnaEricson If the value length is unknown then change `{32}` to `+` for 1 or more characters. Or, if you know that the length is between say 10 and 50 characters then include a range quantifier instead, eg. `{10,50}`. Also, if this is not a hex value then you'll need to change the preceding character class from `[0-9a-f]` to something more specific (or generic) according to your values.